# REST API not working

Tags: java, rest, nagios

If we run the following command in command line, it works fine. But when we run this command from nagios based tool, it failes with an ERROR below:-

```
java -jar /opt/monitor/nagios/notify/REST/RestInterface.jar 
/opt/monitor/nagios/notify/REST/settings.xml "2015-10-20 12:57:11" L
```

Result code: 1

**ERROR OUTPUT:**

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for RestInterface.log    
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:389)    
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.(FileHandler.java:363)    
        at com.google.nagios.notify.RestInterface.loggerInit(Unknown Source)    
        at com.google.nagios.notify.RestInterface.main(Unknown Source)    
Oct 20, 2015 12:57:11 PM com.google.nagios.notify.RestInterface logToOS  
SEVERE: null  
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "EVENTCREATE": error=2, No such file   or directory    
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)    
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)    
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)    
          at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)    
        at com.google.nagios.notify.RestInterface.logToOS(Unknown Source)    
         at com.google.nagios.notify.RestInterface.loggerInit(Unknown Source)    
        at com.google.nagios.notify.RestInterface.main(Unknown Source)  
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory    
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)    
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:186)  
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)    
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)    
        ... 6 more  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException      
        at com.google.nagios.notify.RestInterface.loggerInit(Unknown Source)      
        at com.google.nagios.notify.RestInterface.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: REST API is working with command line, But when this command is run from GUI, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that RestInterface.log is locked by some other process. Just kill the other process so the file can be written.

Comment: How do we know what processes have locked the file, RestInterface.log ?

Comment: REST API is working with command line, But when this command is run from GUI, it doesn't work.

Comment: To check which processes are using your file. Open Terminal --> and type in this command 'ps -ef | grep RestInterface.log' it will show the list of processes using your file. Then kill the process using 'kill -9 processID' command.

Comment: the path of the file was incorrect and it is solved now.